# Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFFramework,Version=v4.6.1'

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When Iuild my solution I am getting below warning message. All my projects are created with ""Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0". My web API build with `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />`

> Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using
> '.NETFFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target
> framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fullay
> compatible with your project.

What's wrong here?

Comment: One of your dependencies is probably using that package. Or, you have by accident referenced in one of your projects, check every .csproj.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As discussed in [this post](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/179) , Packages targeting asp.net core being with Microsoft.AspNetCore. What you're adding is a package for previous versions of WebApi, and whilst it has Core in its name it's not for the Core platform.

There's no specific WebApi package for ASP.NET Core any more, it's all built into Microsoft.AspNetCore.* packages( MVC and the .App or .All package) . And this repo does produce one compatible package -- [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/).